# java script for validation on a click of save button

Tags: javascript

I have a .aspx file in which  i applied Javascript for validation on a click of save button but now i have to use this Javascript code in other file and check validation how can i do that?

Comment: Java !== Javascript... you forgot type safety :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   /*
     your validation code.
   */
</script>
```

Add this script in the head section of other page,

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="validation.js"></script>
```